# How to tell if my model is overfitting? 99.96% accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

After training my dataset through 10 epoches, I reached the below accuracy:

511767/511767 [==============================] - 189s 370us/sample - loss: 0.0036 - accuracy: 0.9996 - val_loss: 0.0019 - val_accuracy: 0.9998

On this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud

I used SMOTE to bump up the minority class and used LSTM for my model.

Confusion matrix:

array([[28370,     9],
       [    5, 28479]], dtype=int64)

So how can i tell if my model is overfitting?

It seems to be doing very well and an accuracy of .9996 seems very high, alas i have made sure to train on an equal labelled dataset

Here's my model

```py
#Model configuration
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1,29), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer = 'adam',
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

Here is my oversampling code

```py
#Data pre processing, splitting and resampling
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
transactions = pd.read_csv('creditcard.csv').drop('Time', axis=1)
transactions['Amount'] = transactions['Amount'] / 25691.160000
X = np.array(transactions.drop('Class', axis=1))
y = np.array(transactions['Class'])
X, y = BorderlineSMOTE().fit_resample(X, y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], 1, x_test.shape[1]))
```

Comment: Usually (but not necessarily) validation set is something that can tell you that your model is overfitting. However, in your case, the dataset classes are heavily unbalanced- i.e. only 0.172% of your actual dataset is True Positive (fraudulent). So incase you're randomly generating a validation set from the same distribution, you'll have the same problem i.e. your model can predict every item as 'non-fraudulent' and you'd still get ~99.8% accuracy!

Comment: You can try crafting a balanced test-set (or validation) i.e. 50% non-fraudulent and 50% fraudulent transactions and then see what you get ;) Or (and) take some other metric into consideration like f1 score too.

Comment: @DaveIdito That is what i done, i used SMOTE to balance the dataset. Sorry i didn't include the code in my question - i have just done so now. Can you review my question now and re answer

Comment: What does your model predict `model.predict(x_test)` where `x_test` is all 'fraudulent' cases and vice-versa? Confusion matrix should be enough but I'm sorry I'm having hard time interpreting one; sorry only TIL about SMOTE.

Comment: Assuming your labels are binary (1, 0), you can do this: `only_positive_y = np.where(y_test == 1, True, False)`, then `only_positive_x = x_test[only_positive_y]` and then check the predictions.

Comment: @DaveIdito Thank you